# NSMutableDictionary key value shuffled

Tags: ios, iphone, key-value, nsmutabledictionary

I am facing very strange problem in NSMutableDictionary. Please see the below code.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [dict setValue:@"India" forKey:(@"Title")];
 [dict setValue:@"Done" forKey:(@"Status")];
```

When I had printed this dictionary object, It shows like below.

```
{
Status =Done,
Title=India;
}
```

This keys getting shuffled, actually Title key should come first.

So, How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: As far as I know a Dictionary is not ordered. If you need order, use an NSArray.

Comment: Why you need order? BTW thats not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

**That's not an issue.**

You have mis understood or you'r getting wrong the `NSDictionary`. `NSDictionary` is a container to store values base on the keys.

**So, there is no need of any order or indexing.**

Reason behind is that you can only access container value if you know the key. So it is meaning less to check order of that keys. Because any how you have to use that key to access related value.

Now about order - Use `NSArray` instead and more of that use `NSArray` with object of `NSDictionary`. So that you have order with dictionary support.

Still the way to sort dictionary keys is below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:@"India" forKey:(@"Title")];
[dict setValue:@"Done" forKey:(@"Status")];

NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSLog(@"%@",keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary does not guarantee any ordering of it's key/value pairs. There's no way to keep your keys/values in a set order and it doesn't make sense for NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary to work like this. (You use keys not indexes to retrieve values).

If you want your values or keys in a certain order for display purposes you can sort them after retrieving them:

```
NSArray * sortedKeys = [ [ myDictionary allKeys ] sortedArrayUsingSelector:... ] ;
```

or

```
NSArray * sortedKeys = [ [ myDictionary allKeys ] sortedArrayUsingComparator:... ] ;
```

You could then retrieve the associated objects for the sorted keys if you wanted.

Another option is to maintain 2 separate arrays, one for keys and one for values and keep them in order.